# How to read large Prolog files in ECLiPSe?

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

I generated a large file of paths via eclipse. Each line contains a clause for a list of 27 points.

```
$ wc -l snake_points.pl
240917 snake_points.pl

$ ls -lh snake_points.pl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 carl carl 72M Sep  6 02:39 snake_points.pl

$ head -n 1 snake_points.pl 
snake_points([(2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2), (0, 2, 2), (0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]).
```

However, I am unable to load the file into memory (even with 8G of heap):

```
$ time eclipse -f snake_points.ecl -e 'halt.'
*** Overflow of the global/trail stack in spite of garbage collection!
You can use the "-g kBytes" (GLOBALSIZE) option to have a larger stack.
Peak sizes were: global stack 8388576 kbytes, trail stack 59904 kbytes

________________________________________________________
Executed in  128.05 secs   fish           external 
   usr time  122.92 secs  297.00 micros  122.92 secs 
   sys time    5.01 secs   37.00 micros    5.01 secs
```

Compare this to `swipl`:

```
$ time swipl -f snake_points.pl -g 'halt.'

________________________________________________________
Executed in   53.56 secs   fish           external 
   usr time   53.27 secs  272.00 micros   53.27 secs 
   sys time    0.28 secs   41.00 micros    0.28 secs
```

Neither are impressive, but I'd expect ECLiPSe to complete with a reasonable amount of memory.

Is this expected behavior? What can be done?

I understand the solution may be "use a database" or EXDR, but shouldn't this be able to be done efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not only reading the data, you are trying to compile it as a single predicate with 240917 clauses, and the compiler is indeed not built for this kind of usage.

You can instead read and assert the clauses from the data file one-by-one, like this:

```
assert_from_file(File) :-
        open(File, read, S),
        repeat,
            read(S, Term),
            ( Term == end_of_file ->
                true
            ;
                assert(Term),
                fail
            ),
        !, close(S).
```

This loads your data in finite time

```
?- assert_from_file("snake_points.pl").
Yes (19.38s cpu)
```

and you can then call the resulting predicate as expected

```
?- snake_points(X).
X = [(2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2), (0, 2, 2), (0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, ..., ...), (..., ...), ...]
Yes (0.04s cpu, solution 1, maybe more) ? ;
```

But whatever problem you are trying to solve, this doesn't look like the most promising approach...

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just write a file with a `dynamic/1` and an `include/1` directives declaring the `snake_points/1` predicate as dynamic and including the original `snake_points.pl` file?

Comment: @Paulo, unfortunately no. The compiler, as currently written, still sucks in all clauses for a predicate in one go, causing a problem.

Comment: Using `dynamic/1` and `include/1` actually completed with 8gb in about ~60s.

Comment: Using `assert_from_file` completed with 1gb in ~22s.

Using `assert_from_file` with @PauloMoura's suggestion resulted in the best performance with 1gb in under 9s!

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried changing the points representation? Using `','/2` to represent tuples with more than two elements per tuple is a bad idea. Note that:

```
[eclipse 30]: write_canonical((1,2,3)).
','(1, ','(2, 3))
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Try instead e.g. `p(1,2,3)`. This should lower memory requirements a bit and may make a difference.

Comment: This reduces the memory usage to ~500MB and completes in 40 seconds. Thanks!